# Specific case of using virtual method

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have the following code which return "YXX".
I would like to know why the second print displays an 'X' whereas the key-word `virtual` is used in the class X. So the line `tab[0] = y1` will be set tab[0] as an Y object and displays 'Y' due to the virtual method isn't it ?

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
    public: virtual void f() const { std::cout << "X"; }
};

class Y : public X {
    void f() const { std::cout << "Y"; }
};

void print(const X &x) { x.f(); }

int main() {
    X tab[2];
    Y y1;
    tab[0] = y1;

    print(y1);
    print(tab[0]);
    print(tab[1]);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to use pointers

Comment: Look up object slicing.

Comment: For polymorphism you need pointers or references to the base class, initialized to point to a child class. I also recommend you use [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) when overriding functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tab is an array of X objects, so when you assign the Y object to an element of tab it slices off the Y portions and you are left with just the X part.

Now, if you changed it to:

```
X * tab[2];
tab[0] = new X;
tab[1] = new Y;
print(*tab[0]);
print(*tab[1]);
```

It  would not do any slicing and it would print XY